# binary file(pdf) from database on web page using PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, file, binary

I have uploaded a pdf file (varbinary(MAX)) in MSSQL running on my desktop via VS2010 ([Ref](http://www.trigonblue.com/Text_Market/Load_Image_to_SQL_Server_2005.htm)) with just the UPDATE statement in the Ref.

The table has additional data associated with the pdf, like name, description, date.

Table in database:

```
Name       |  Description    |    Date      |    File            |

DataSheet  |  Milling M/C    |  2004-01-01  |    <Binary data>   |
```

Is it possible to display the table content in a web page as

```
Name       |  Description    |    Date      |    File            |`

DataSheet  |  Milling M/C    |  2004-01-01  | (link to the pdf)  |
```

or

```
Name       |  Description    |    Date      |    File            |

DataSheet  |  Milling M/C    |  2004-01-01  | (an icon of pdf)   |
```

using PHP so that user can click the link/file to view it. There will be lot of rows, I just gave 1 row for example.

Please let me know if I am not clear, thanks in advance.

PS: I did create some images but was not able to post them, sorry about the format

---

What I have done so far

---

I am using 'Connect without a DSN (using a connection string)' from [here](http://www.webcheatsheet.com/PHP/connect_mssql_database.php)

```
$conn = new COM ("ADODB.Connection") or die("Cannot start ADO");

$connStr = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;SERVER=".$myServer.";UID=".$myUser.";PWD=".$myPass.";DATABASE=".$myDB;

$conn->open($connStr);

$query = "select * from Table";

$rs = $conn->execute($query);

$num_columns = $rs->Fields->Count();

for ($i=0; $i < $num_columns; $i++) {
$fld[$i] = $rs->Fields($i);
    }

while (!$rs->EOF)
{
for ($i=0; $i < $num_columns; $i++) {
echo $fld[$i]->value;
    }   
$rs->MoveNext();    
}
```

The result I am getting is garbage for binary data.

```
DataSheet | Milling M/C | 2004-01-01 | some_garbage |
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. Create a link to a separate page that accepts a record is in the query string. For instance, you can link to `ViewFile.php?recordid=123`.

Then, in ViewFile.php, you can get the binary data, output some headers, and output the binary (I think even echo would suffice for that).

The headers should contain at least a `Content-Type` header, telling the browser that the binary data is to be interpreted as `application/pdf` data. If it is not a pdf, you should specify appropriate headers. Lists of valid Content-Types can be found all over the internet.

You can specify a filename too. But the important thing is that you can determine what kind of data it is. If you don't know whether it is an icon or a pdf, you cannot tell the browser either. The browser will need to know (by reading the content-type header) how the data should be interpreted. It cannot guess it, even when the url would have a .pdf extension.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am very new to all the stuff. I will try and let you know what I did. Right now, below is what I have so far.

Comment: I was not able to get the formatting I want, so will edit my question or post as answer.

Comment: @GolezTrol , this time I followed ['Connect with a DSN'](http://www.webcheatsheet.com/PHP/connect_mssql_database.php).
    
`$query=<query to select just one <Binary Data>;`
    
`$result=odbc_exec($conn, $query);`
    
`$outputPdf=odbc_result($result, 1);`
    
`header("Content-type: application/pdf");`
    
`echo $outputPdf;`
    
and the output is still garbage. Am I doing something wrong, please advise, thanks again.

Comment: Hmm I found an example that does just about that: http://www.wellho.net/resources/ex.php4?item=h110/pdfget.php But it could be an encoding problem. I'm not sure...

Comment: Is there any way you can check if the php file contains valid data? Mayby you can save the data to a file, both from PHP and from PHPMyAdmin or whichever tool you are using. If that does work, then it's in transporting the data through PHP. If that doesn't give you a good PDF file, the data in the database itself may be corrupt.

Comment: @GolezTrol , I tried [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/008d0a0d-e75e-4d11-a89b-cbae4e086c23/) in VS2010 with 2 pdf files and was able to save, open the pdf.s in my desktop. Guess the data in the database is not corrupt. Please advise, thanks lot of your help.